# RGBa css vs aRGB Android

Tags: android, css, rgba, argb

I need to port this codehttp://www.pahgawks.com/blog/fire-particles-for-html5-canvas/ from css and javascript to Android.
in this code if change this line

```
stage.fillStyle = "rgba("+(260-(particles[i].life*2))+","+((particles[i].life*2)+50)+","+(particles[i].life*2)+","+(((max-particles[i].life)/max)*0.4)+")";
```

to:

```
stage.fillStyle = "rgba("+255+","+50+","+0+","+0.4+")";
```

see fire with yellow and red and white color but in Android I see just red color

```
paint.setColor(Color.argb(102,255,50,0);
```

but I have problem with paint.setColor(Color.argb(alpha,red,green,blue)) and rgba css
in the css code we see a color read yellow and white that created in fire.

Answer (score 0):

In your Java code, you have a static color (`Color.argb(102, 255, 50, 0)`) when it is dynamically set in JavaScript (based on `particles[i].life` and `max` value).

Try using these value in your Java code too, in order to see all the colors.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know why Android choose to use #ARGB color layout instead of canonical #RGBA color layout. Here comes a news of [hex value handling](https://developer.android.com/preview/behavior-changes#hex-value-handling) in the coming Android P.

> Android P apps enable the draft CSS Color Module Level 4 behaviour for
>   handling 4 and 8 hex digit CSS colors.
>
> CSS Color Module Level 4 has been supported by Chrome since release
>   52, but WebView currently disables the feature because existing
>   Android applications were found to contain 32 bit hex colors in the
>   Android ordering (ARGB), which would cause rendering errors.
>
> For example, the color #80ff8080 is currently rendered in WebView as
>   **opaque** light red (#ff8080) for apps targeting pre-Android P SDKs. **The leading component (which would be interpreted by Android as the alpha component) is currently ignored.** If an app targets P or above,
>   this will be interpreted as 50% transparent light green (#80ff80).